# how to check if the integer is between -20 to +20 in c++

Tags: c++

I want to check my integer value if it lies between - 20 to + 20 based on that i want to do further operation. How to check it by loop?

```
   for(int m=-20;m<=20;m++)
          {
              if(diff==m)

              {
                value=1; 
              }

          }
```

Is it correct?

Comment: @bavani..what is diff?

Comment: Please learn http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm

Comment: @phresnel Because this is basic for any language

Comment: @ling.s: Exactly; it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use an loop - just an if conditional:

```
if((diff >= -20) && (diff <= 20)){
  // do something
}
```

`&&` is the logical AND Operator - it connects multiple conditions and the expression evaluates only to true, if both conditions are fullfilled.

See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Logical_operators)

Answer (score 5):

### Between? What's that?

First, **define what *"between"* means**.

- Does it mean -20 is valid or invalid?
- Is 20 included or excluded?

*The real-life "between" is ambiguous*. When you have to find a place *between* two people, you probably do not want to sit on their face. When you attend a party where they advertise *between ages 18 and 88*, they mean to include age 18.

This is a basic, but security critical decision. A symptom of not thinking about this is one of the most widespread bugs, the so called [Off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_by_one).

### Intervals

This is something that should be in your programmer's toolbox: In maths, you can express the four cases with [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29):

- `[a..b]` <- a and b are included
- `(a..b]` <- a is not included, but everything bigger than a and smaller than b is
- `[a..b)` <- b is not included, but everything smaller than b and bigger than a is
- `(a..b)` <- a and b are both not included, but everything bigger than a and smaller than b is

### Implementation

The canonical implementation of interval checks in languages whose syntax is derived from C is as follows:

```
if (x>=-20 && x<=20) {<code>}  // if x in [-20..20], then do <code>
if (x>-20  && x<=20) {<code>}  // if x in (-20..20], then do <code>
if (x>=-20 && x<20)  {<code>}  // if x in [-20..20), then do <code>
if (x>-20  && x<20)  {<code>}  // if x in (-20..20), then do <code>
```

Here, `&&` is the logical-and operator (we call it so because there is also a bitwise-and operator). It is the C-equivalent (and syntax-derived languages) of [logical conjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) and is `true` if both operands have a value of `true`.

In most C-syntax derived languages, the operator `&&` has a lower, so-called, *precedence* than the comparison operators `<=`, `<`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=`, so whether you put the left operand and the operand to `&&` in parentheses, i.e.

```
   x>=-20 && x<=20 
vs. 
   (x>=-20) && (x<=20)
```

is typically just a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason to check inside of a loop? I mean, is there other processing happening in the loop? Otherwise, I recommend looking at the `&&` operator in an `if`-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know If condition?. The most basic kind of conditional branch in `C++` is the if statement. If the expression evalutes to true (non-zero), the statement executes

```
if(m>=-20 && m<=20)
{
// stuff
}
```

Syntax:

```
if (expression)
statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the integer is m

```
if(m>=-20 && m<=20)
{

  value=1;

}
```

No need of a for loop here only if condition is enough..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do by:

```
if( (m>= -20) && (m<=20))
{
//Do some thing.
}
```

No need to go for loop.